# default_if_none requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

Tags: python, django, django-templates, frontend, django-template-filters

I used [default_if_none](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) as shown below:

```
<input type="text" name='username' value="{{ value|default_if_none: '' }}">
```

But, I got the error below:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: default_if_none requires 2 arguments, 1 provide

So, how can I solve the error?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have an extra space which causes the error.

```
value="{{ value|default_if_none: '' }}"
```

should be

```
value="{{ value|default_if_none:'' }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Django template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference), putting space either before or after `:` gets error as shown below:

```
                            # Space (Error)
                               ↓ ↓
value="{{ value|default_if_none : '' }}"
```

So, don't put any space there not to get error as shown below:

```
                         # No space (No error)
                              ↓ ↓
value="{{ value|default_if_none:'' }}"
```

In addition, putting space either before or after `|` doesn't get error:

```
            # Space (No error)
               ↓ ↓
value="{{ value | default_if_none:'' }}"
```